# Recovering VVV after a host crash

Tags: wordpress, macos, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

I use vvv to develop WordPress sites locally. I left everything (the host Mac, vagrant, gulp) running last night and for whatever reason the host Mac crashed. The Mac started up fine this morning but the vagrant is not working. My assumption is that files in the guest were corrupted.

What steps should I take to get things back in order? 
$ vagrant provision

$ vagrant box update

(I'm hamstrung at the moment since there's DDoS attack on Dyn so I can't reach ubuntu.com or github.com so those commands are really working)

Comment: Try getting `vagrant status`. If it's just `aborted`, run `vagrant up` again. No need to provision or update the vm.

Comment: try starting your VM directly from VirtualBox and see if its fine from there, if anything VBox will give you more information than vagrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting things back to a known, off state was the trick. For whatever reason vagrant halt didn't shut down the virtualbox. 'vagrant status' was the trick. That showed the vm running. Shutting it down via the VirutalBox UI and the 'vagrant up --provision' had me back and working.